# Export nfs to devices in the local ip range without specifying local ip

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

I have a system which contains a number of raspberry pi's, one of which is a 'master' which must export an nfs to a number of 'slave' devices in the system.

The system will be connected to the end users network; the end user will be able to specify an ip subnet range on which the pi's must communicate.

To cut down on setup complexity for the end user, is it possible to specify in /etc/exports to share with only the local ip address of the pi?

Something like:

```
/home      local-ip/255.255.255.0(ro)
```

To be clear: If the end user sets the ip of the pi's to be in the 10.0.1.x range or the 192.168.5.x range, is it possible for exports to automatically use this range without modifying /etc/exports? I don't want to export to all ip's.

Other info: The user has no communication with the system while in use. The SD card for the pi has a small FAT partition which the end user can mount in a windows computer and modify an interfaces file which is sourced by /etc/network/interfaces to allow them to change the ip. The /etc/exports does not appear to support sourcing from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `/etc/exports` can not be sourced by conventional methods - you can however script the contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip_info=$(ip a | grep inet | grep -v "127.0.0.1" | cut -d " " -f 6)
range=$(echo $ip_info | sed 's/\.[0-9]\+\//\.0\//g')
echo "/home/              $range(ro)" > /etc/exports
exportfs
/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Place that with your favorite editor in `/root/set_nfs_exports.sh` and make it executable

```
chmod +x /root/set_nfs_exports.sh
```

and have it executed after the network interface comes up

```
ln -s /root/set_nfs_exports.sh /etc/network/if-up.d/export-nfs
```

Hope this helps